# Can't create an SQLite table on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-sqlite

I have been following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases) in its entirety, on how to store data in a local database. On iOS everything works fine, unfortunately on android i get an exception upon creating a table in my database file. The method for creating the table is:

```
public CalcDatabase(string dbPath)
{
  database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
  database.CreateTableAsync<Calculation>().Wait();
}
```

And my custom class for getting the database path on Android is as follows:

```
public class LocalFileHelper : IFileHelper
{
     public string GetLocalFilePath(string filename)
     {
         var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
         path = Path.Combine(path, filename);

         if(!Directory.Exists(path))
         {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
         }

         return path;
     }
}
```

This is the error that im getting from SQLite:

> Could not open database file: /data/user/0/com.companyname.XX/files/Calculation.db3 (CannotOpen)

I have tried targeting several different APIs, I have tried to clean and rebuild my solution, and I have tried to reinstall the SQLite-net-pcl NuGet packages across the whole solution. Nothing works.

I have read, that it has to do with permissions, still, I do however find it strange that the official Microsoft tutorial doesn't cover this if it was a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check out the Android Permissions declaration (and grants) for Write and Read to external storage on your device or emulator.

It must be enough.

Make sure to delete `bin` and `obj` folders, clean and rebuild solution to get rid of any cached data on app compilation.